# Unordered_set variable private vs public, best practice?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

I have a simple code for unordered map in C++. Now I have declared my variable defined as unordered_map as private and explicitly wrote insert delete and print function in public, which are nothing but merely calling unordered member functions like insert, delete, and iterative search.

Can someone please tell me if this is right approach because if this is then we will have to write explicit public function for all the member function. For instance load_factor will have its own, testing whether the set is empty or not will be second one and list will go on and on.

If we just declare my variable in public then we would just write one line code in class and we dont have to write explicit functions to perform member functions from objects.

So what would you choose? Less code or more security?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

class unordered_set_class {

        private:
            unordered_set<string> mystring = { "White", "Black", "Brown" };


        public:
            bool insert_item(string name);
            bool delete_item(string name);
            void print();

};

void unordered_set_class::print(){

    for(auto itr = mystring.begin(); itr != mystring.end(); ++itr){
        cout << *itr << "\t";
    }

    cout << "\n";

}

bool unordered_set_class::insert_item(string name){

      mystring.insert(name);
      return true;
}

bool unordered_set_class::delete_item(string name){

     mystring.erase(name);
     return true;
}

int main(){

    class unordered_set_class t;
    t.insert_item("yellow");
    t.print();
    string x = "White";
    t.delete_item(x);
    t.print();
    cout << "Load Factor = " << t.mystring.load_factor() << "\n";

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The right approach may be not to write a class and just use an `unordered_set<string>`. It isn't clear from your question why you use a class.

Comment: Because now I am going to have multiple things inside this class. I started with unordered map but now I will have vectors, ordered map, set etc etc

Comment: Think about may be tomorrow you don't want `unordered_map` as the underlying data structure, but something else.What would be better approach?

Comment: Also I am curious about the right approach. Seems like if you are suggesting it to declare without class then having it private doesnt make any sense and could have been public, right?

Comment: Gaurav, I know you are hinting towards templates but I am new to C++ and learning the basic concepts so playing with different approach but of course I want to know the best code writing style.

Comment: The main question should be what's the point of that class you are writing. If it is only for wrapping unordered_set then it's not really necessary.

Comment: Describe the purpose of this class. What's it intended to do, what functionality do you want to add to it later and why? What do you need vectors, map, sets to be in the same class for? Impossible to answer without this information.

Comment: I am just learning. So trying to figure out the right way of writing code. I am new to C++. Suppose we have a class where we have unordered_map, set and other unordered container. So is it good practice to have them in private and then have public functions or is it common to have them in public?